# Allowing a user to resize a image on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section of my webpage that contains media, mostly pictures. I want the user to be able to re-size the picture to whatever size he/she wants. I was hoping the user would be able to drag a corner to re-size the picture if that is possible.
Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/anstw7Lu/ 
 Here is the HTML:

```
 <div id="media-section">
   <!--Title -->
  <div id="media-title">Media</div>

  <div id="media-button" class="button-container">
  <!-- The panel that will display the content -->
  <div id="media-content"><br><br>
    Here is my picture<br><img src="http://circleofdocs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bigstock-Coconut-isolated-on-white-back-70653349.jpg" height=200px width=200px>
    <br> I want to be able to resize this picture, make it larger, smaller, ect.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my answer : update code as per your fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create resize element or image from user side, you need to use **[Resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)** which allow you to resize an element

```js
$(function() {
    $( "img" ).resizable();
  });
```

```css
#media-section{
 float:left;
 text-align: center;
 height:500px;
 width: 250px;
 border-style: solid
}
#media-title{
    height:6%;
 width:100%;
 float:left; 
 font-size:24px;
}
#media-button{
 height:4%;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 border-style: solid;
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
}
#media{
 width:100%;
 height:92.5%;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="media-section">
    <!--Title -->
    <div id="media-title">Media</div>

    <div id="media-button" class="button-container">
        <!-- Button that when clicked activates a dalog box for the passage. -->
        <button id="max-media" class="max"></button>
    </div>
 
    <!-- The panel that will display the content -->
    <div id="media-content">
        Here is my picture<br><img id="resizable" src="http://circleofdocs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bigstock-Coconut-isolated-on-white-back-70653349.jpg" height=200px width=200px>
        <br> I want to be able to resize this picture, make it larger, smaller, ect.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. However, the page I am creating is dynamic. Text is loaded in via a JSON file. The section that is loaded in has text and an image tag. example: `"media":"Rulers of Corinth<br><img src='img/Rulers-of-Corinth.jpg'height='250' width='250px'",`  It is easier to add CSS styling rather than 100's of functions for each separate img tag.  I should have mentioned that in the original question.  It is my fault.

Comment: You just need to use `$( "img" ).resizable();` for the same, i have update my code. you can up vote for the code if you would like

Comment: Well that fixes that issue haha. Thank you so very much buddy.

Answer (score 3):

#### CSS3

You can use a new CSS3 feature called **Box Resizing**. You should add this to your stylesheet:

```
img {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Reference:** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

You might also want to consider using    **JavaScript**, which may have wider browser support. You can use jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<div>` with your image as a background and then allow resizing through CSS.

```css
.image {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/203/130/100');
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  resize: both;
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```